# Changes in the kernel across versions

Tags: evaluation, kernel, internals

I was going through the Power programming book by David Wagner, and I tried:

```
s = Range[10000000];
Do[s[[i]] = (s[[i]] + s[[i + 1]])/2, {i, 1, 
    Length@s - 1}]; // RepeatedTiming
Clear@s
s = Range[10000000];
t = Table[0, {i, 1, 10000000}];
Do[t[[i]] = (s[[i]] + s[[i + 1]])/2, {i, 1, 
    Length@s - 1}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

Which is a version of his example in section (7.3.3) with a larger list s. The point is that he got a factor of 5 in time from the first to the second version( 3 seconds to 0.6). On the other hand, I went from 16.3 to 15.2 seconds, no considerable improvement. He gave an explanation of why the second version was faster: When you call a list that was modified in the last access Mathematica scans the whole list even if you are calling one particular term, so in the first Do loop you would be scanning the whole list "s" at every iteration, and in the second that doesn't happen. However, the fact that I hardly get any improvement when I tried, makes me wonder if this is not how it works anymore, if the kernel now operates differently since version 3, which was the current version when the book was written.

Comment: I cannot imagine how it was ever that fast. Regardless, you can check by varying the list sizes that the complexity in both is linear, not quadratic. Granted, the first might have been quadratic back when the book was written.

Comment: I may have been unclear, in the book the "s" list had only 1000 elements, the one I did was bigger to account for the fact that chips are faster now. However, that is the question, if both scale linearly now something changed on how Mathematica executes the operations, what was it?

Comment: There were changes to help avoid reevaluations (by quickly determining they are not needed) after expressions are altered. This is not perfect but works far more often tha

Comment: Cool, how can I get access to that information?

Comment: I have no idea. These changes have come about over decades and I'm not even sure I know which ones are responsible for this particular improvement (I know the general class but not the specific one(s)). I guess this is not institutional knowledge so much as folklore, at this point.